# Proguard error while signing APK with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to debug my error with Proguard. My project is working fine with debug but not with Proguard. Any help will be appreciated.

1. I have tried with `ignore warning` in Proguard. However application is crashing with generated APK.
2. Current Proguard settings is not working. Messages console I have uploaded to [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dasbiswajit/9e0bc35f0da55052c70f03921629c657)
3. Build.gradle is given below
4. Prodguard-project.txt in [gist](https://gist.github.com/dasbiswajit/0f5481882d55f45d11b6d378060070ed)

   ```
   buildscript {
     repositories {
       jcenter()
     }

     dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
     }
   }
   ```

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/codequality.gradle')
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
      versionCode 49
      versionName "1.8.8"

      minSdkVersion 14
      targetSdkVersion 22

      buildConfigField 'String', 'BUILD_TAG', '"' + getBuildTag() + '"'
      buildConfigField 'String', 'OWM_API_KEY', '"' + getOpenWeatherMapApiKey() + '"'
      buildConfigField 'boolean', 'ENABLE_WEATHER', 'true'

      def buildSuffix = getBuildSuffix(versionName, versionCode)
      applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def file = variant.outputs[0].outputFile
        variant.outputs[0].outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + buildSuffix + ".apk"))
      }
    }

    if (project.hasProperty('signingKeyStoreFile')) {
      signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile     file(signingKeyStoreFile)
            storePassword signingKeyStorePassword
            keyAlias      signingKeyAlias
            keyPassword   signingKeyPassword
        }
      }
    }

    buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled true
         proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
         if (project.hasProperty('signingKeyStoreFile')) {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
         }
       }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
  }

  def getBuildSuffix(versionName, versionCode) {
    def suffix = versionName + '-' + versionCode
    if (System.getenv()['BUILD_NUMBER'] != null) {
        suffix += '-b' + System.getenv()['BUILD_NUMBER']
    }
    return suffix
  }

  def getBuildTag() {
    def tag = ''
    if (System.getenv()['BUILD_NUMBER'] != null) {
        tag += 'b' + System.getenv()['BUILD_NUMBER']
    } else {
        tag += 'l'
    }
    tag += '@' + new Date().format('yyyyMMdd')
    return tag
  }

  def getOpenWeatherMapApiKey() {
    if (project.hasProperty('owmApiKey')) {
        return owmApiKey
    } else {
        def apiKeyFile = file('default_owm_api_key');
        if (apiKeyFile.isFile()) {
          return apiKeyFile.text.trim()
        }
    }
    return 'NOKEY'
  }

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Dependencies

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {

    //compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
  }
  configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
  }

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Checkstyle

  task checkstyleDebug(type: Checkstyle, dependsOn: 'compileDebugSources') {
    source = fileTree('src/main/java/')
    classpath = files('build/intermediates/classes/debug')
  }
check.dependsOn checkstyleDebug

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Findbugs

  task findbugsDebug(type: FindBugs, dependsOn: 'compileDebugSources') {
    source = fileTree('src/main/java/')
    classes = fileTree('build/intermediates/classes/debug')
    classpath = files() // empty classpath!
    effort = 'max'
    excludeFilter = rootProject.file('config/findbugs/androidExcludeFilter.xml')
  }
  check.dependsOn findbugsDebug

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // PMD

  task pmd(type: Pmd) {
    source = fileTree('src/main/java/')
    ruleSets = ['java-basic', 'java-braces', 'java-android']
  }
  check.dependsOn 'pmd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` to the `proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'`, to get next row:

`proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'`
Or start to search the issues from your proguard-project.txt, like:

1. Add rule `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,InnerClasses,Signature,Exceptions`
2. Add rule `-dontwarn com.google.**`
   And so on, by your proguard failed logs

Comment: do i need to add 'proguard-android.txt' file explicitly if I take the first method mentioned.@LifeStyle

Comment: no, try without or try with getDefaultProguardFile(proguard-android-optimize.txt) but with fixed proguard rules as menitioned above

Comment: 1. Do I need to add proguard-android-optimize.txt file explicitly as it is not present currently. 2. alter **proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'** with **getDefaultProguardFile(proguard-android-optimize.txt)**. Correct me please. i have to release with out prodguard looks like.

Comment: You can try ti use with or without. proguard-android.txt and proguard-android-optimize.txt are default proguard android rules. You can add them or not, but if you have optimize flags in your own proguard file and added proguard-android.txt then optimization won't be performed. So it is your decission what to use and if use at all. But for beginning try without proguard `getDefaultProguardFile(proguard-android-optimize.txt). ` only with your proguard-project.txt